# R_Extract the row and column of the element in use when using apply function

Tags: r, apply

How to extract the row and column of the element in use when using `apply` function? For example, say  I want to apply a function for each element of the matrix where row and column number of the selected element are also variables in the function. A simple reproducible example is given below

```
mymatrix <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4)
```

I want a function which does the following

```
apply(mymatrix, c(1,2), function (x) sum(x, row_number, col_number))
```

where `row_number` and `col_number` are the row and column number of the selected element in `mymatrix`. Note that my function is more complicated than `sum`, so a robust solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do but I would use a `for` loop here.

Pre-allocate the return `matrix` and this will be very fast

```
ret <- mymatrix
for (i in 1:nrow(mymatrix))
    for (j in 1:ncol(mymatrix))
        ret[i, j] <- sum(mymatrix[i, j], i, j)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    7   11   15
#[2,]    5    9   13   17
#[3,]    7   11   15   19
```

---

### Benchmark analysis 1

I was curious so I ran a `microbenchmark` analysis to compare methods; I used a bigger `200x300` matrix.

```
mymatrix <- matrix(1:600, nrow = 200, ncol = 300)
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    for_loop = {
        ret <- mymatrix
        for (i in 1:nrow(mymatrix))
            for (j in 1:ncol(mymatrix))
                ret[i, j] <- sum(mymatrix[i, j], i, j)
    },
    expand_grid_mapply = {
        newResult<- mymatrix
        grid1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mymatrix),1:ncol(mymatrix))
        newResult[]<-
        mapply(function(row_number, col_number){ sum(mymatrix[row_number, col_number], row_number, col_number) },row_number = grid1$Var1, col_number = grid1$Var2 )
    },
    expand_grid_apply = {
        newResult<- mymatrix
        grid1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mymatrix),1:ncol(mymatrix))
        newResult[]<-
        apply(grid1, 1, function(x){ sum(mymatrix[x[1], x[2]], x[1], x[2]) })
    },
    double_sapply = {
        sapply(1:ncol(mymatrix), function (x) sapply(1:nrow(mymatrix), function (y) sum(mymatrix[y,x],x,y)))
    }
)

res
#Unit: milliseconds
#               expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max
#           for_loop  41.42098  52.72281  56.86675  56.38992  59.1444  82.89455
# expand_grid_mapply 126.98982 161.79123 183.04251 182.80331 196.1476 332.94854
#  expand_grid_apply 295.73234 354.11661 375.39308 375.39932 391.6888 562.59317
#      double_sapply  91.80607 111.29787 120.66075 120.37219 126.0292 230.85411

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

### Benchmark analysis 2 (with `expand.grid` outside of `microbenchmark`)

```
grid1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mymatrix),1:ncol(mymatrix))
res <- microbenchmark(
    for_loop = {
        ret <- mymatrix
        for (i in 1:nrow(mymatrix))
            for (j in 1:ncol(mymatrix))
                ret[i, j] <- sum(mymatrix[i, j], i, j)
    },
    expand_grid_mapply = {
        newResult<- mymatrix
        newResult[]<-
        mapply(function(row_number, col_number){ sum(mymatrix[row_number, col_number], row_number, col_number) },row_number = grid1$Var1, col_number = grid1$Var2 )
    },
    expand_grid_apply = {
        newResult<- mymatrix
        newResult[]<-
        apply(grid1, 1, function(x){ sum(mymatrix[x[1], x[2]], x[1], x[2]) })
    }
)

res
#Unit: milliseconds
#               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max
#           for_loop  39.65599  54.52077  60.87034  59.19354  66.64983  95.7890
# expand_grid_mapply 130.33573 167.68201 194.39764 186.82411 209.33490 400.9273
#  expand_grid_apply 296.51983 373.41923 405.19549 403.36825 427.41728 597.6937
```

Comment: I think this approach is much clearer for a beginner.

Comment: @AndreElrico Perhaps, I went for the `mapply`/`Map` approach first as well though;-) I was curious how both would compare so added a `microbenchmark` comparison.

Comment: thanks for the benchmark, i learned something. I would be currious about how it would look like if the expand.grid is outside of the benchmark.

Comment: I was trying to avoid `for` loop thinking it would take longer for a big matrix. Thanks for proving it wrong.

Comment: @AndreElrico Done;-) That's interesting, I would've expected `expand.grid` to be the main culprit but that doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: double for-loop. Still a thing in 2018

Comment: @MaMu Yes, contrary to what you sometimes (often?) hear, `for` loops in R are not inherently slow. In this case we simply replace values in a `matrix` for which we have pre-allocated memory.

Comment: I also figured applying `sapply` twice gives the answer
`sapply(1:ncol(mymatrix), function (x) sapply(1:nrow(mymatrix), 
                                               function (y) sum(mymatrix[y,x],x,y)))`
Can you please compare this method for the speed too? I just don't want to create another answer. Better have one complete answer

Comment: Thanks. Still, the winner is `for` loop :-)

Comment: @MaMu Yes, I'm not so sure why this is, to be honest. I thought at first it might be because in `double_sapply` you're iterating through columns first and then rows, whereas in the `for` loop I iterate through rows first then columns. But even swapping the order doesn't really change the result. It must be the overhead that `sapply` brings, perhaps the implicit `simplify = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how apply works: You cannot access the current index (row, col index) from inside `[lsvm]?apply`-family.

You will have to create the current row and col index before applying. `?expand.grid`.

```
mymatrix <- matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4)
newResult<- mymatrix

grid1 <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mymatrix),1:ncol(mymatrix))

newResult[]<-
mapply(function(row_number, col_number){ sum(mymatrix[row_number, col_number], row_number, col_number) },row_number = grid1$Var1, col_number = grid1$Var2 )

newResult

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    7   11   15
#[2,]    5    9   13   17
#[3,]    7   11   15   19
```

---

If you want to use `apply`

```
newResult[]<-    
apply(grid1, 1, function(x){ sum(mymatrix[x[1], x[2]], x[1], x[2]) })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my thought with `outer()` function.

The third argument `FUN` can be any two-argument function.

```
mymatrix <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
nr <- nrow(mymatrix)
nc <- ncol(mymatrix)
mymatrix + outer(1:nr, 1:nc, FUN = "+")

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    7   11   15
[2,]    5    9   13   17
[3,]    7   11   15   19
```

With @Maurits Evers' benchmark code :

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr       min         lq      mean    median        uq        max
 for_loop 19963.203 22427.1630 25308.168 23811.855 25017.031 158341.678
    outer   848.247   949.3515  1054.944  1011.457  1059.217   1463.956
```

---

In addition, I try to complete your original idea with `apply(X, c(1,2), function (x))` :

(It's a little slower than other answers)

```
mymatrix <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
n <- 1                                        # n = index of data
nr <- nrow(mymatrix)
apply(mymatrix, c(1,2), function (x) {
  row_number <- (n-1) %% nr + 1               # convert n to row number
  col_number <- (n-1) %/% nr + 1              # convert n to column number
  res <- sum(x, row_number, col_number)
  n <<- n + 1
  return(res)
})

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    7   11   15
[2,]    5    9   13   17
[3,]    7   11   15   19
```